# Jenkins : Sending success email only once a day (though the job is running @hourly)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I have a jenkins job configured to run hourly. I want the success build mail to be sent as email only once a day. Email-Ext gives me the option to send emails for all success , failures etc. But what i wanted is the ability to send success email only once.

Comment: Do you want an email to be sent at a specific time every day? And should that mail be sent only if the job is successful or you want the status of the job?

Comment: I wanted a email to be sent at specific time every day and only if its successful.

Comment: @Rajesh just curious -- how did you configure it to run hourly? Was it using @hourly?

Comment: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/generating-a-daily-weekly-report-on-job-status-by-mail-td3766477.html This looks like a solution to me(i haven't tried it though)

Comment: Would it be acceptable to only send the email on failure? No email, assume all is good.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question and you have probably found your own workaround already, but I had a similar need and I thought I'd share my solution anyway.  What I was trying to do was generate a once-daily summary email of jobs in a failed state.   This is fundamentally very similar to sending a once-daily success report for a single job.

My solution uses a Groovy build step coupled with the Email-Ext plugin's pre-send script feature.  I got the idea from the [Nabble thread](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/generating-a-daily-weekly-report-on-job-status-by-mail-td3766477.html) referenced in the comments above.  See also [Email-Ext Recipes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+Recipes) on the Jenkins site.

Here's the initial groovy script that determines which builds are failed, configured under **Execute System Groovy Script**. You could do something similar to determine whether your build succeeded or failed:

```
// List the names of jobs you want to ignore for this check
ignore = [ ]

// Find all failed and unstable jobs
failed = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getView("All").items.findAll{ job ->
  job.getDisplayName() != "Daily Jenkins Job Nag" &&
  !ignore.contains(job.getDisplayName()) &&
  job.isBuildable() &&
  job.lastCompletedBuild &&
  (job.lastCompletedBuild.result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE ||
   job.lastCompletedBuild.result == hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE)
}

// Log the job names so the build results are legible
failed.each { job ->
  println(job.getDisplayName() +
          " " + job.lastCompletedBuild.result +
          " at build " + job.lastCompletedBuild.number +
          " (" + job.lastCompletedBuild.timestamp.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm ZZZZ") + ")");
}

// Return failure if there are any failed jobs
return failed.size
```

Then, down in the **Editable Email Notification** section, I set the Email-Ext plugin to notify on failure.  I set **Content Type** to *Plain Text (text/plain)*, left **Default Content** empty, and set the following as the **Pre-send Script**:

```
failed = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getView("All").items.findAll{ job ->
  job.getDisplayName() != "Daily Jenkins Job Nag" &&
  job.isBuildable() &&
  job.lastCompletedBuild &&
  (job.lastCompletedBuild.result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE ||
   job.lastCompletedBuild.result == hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE)
}

def output = StringBuilder.newInstance()

output << "<html>\n"
output << " <body>\n"
output << "<p>Jenkins reports the following failed jobs:</p>"
output << "  <ul>\n"

failed.each { job ->
  url = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.rootUrl + job.url + "/" + job.lastCompletedBuild.number + "/"
  output << "   <li>"
  output << "<a href=\"" + url  + "\">" + job.displayName + "</a>"
  output << " " + job.lastCompletedBuild.result 
  output << " at build " + job.lastCompletedBuild.number
  output << " (" + job.lastCompletedBuild.timestamp.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm ZZZZ") + ")"
  output << "</li>\n"
}

output << "  </ul>\n"
output << " </body>\n"
output << "</html>"

msg.setContent(output.toString(), "text/html")
```

The key is that you have access to the `msg` object, which is a [MimeMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html). You can set the content of the MIME message to whatever you want.

In this case, I'm generating a list of failed jobs, but in your case it would be whatever message you want to receive for your once-daily success report.  Depending on what you need, you could have Email-Ext send a result for every build rather than just for failed builds.

Answer (score 3):

How about suppressing e-mails if insufficient time has lapsed since the previous e-mail?  Although not precisely what was requested, a pre-send script like this might be worth considering for its simplicity?

```
if (build.result != hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS) {
    cancel = true;
}
else {
  try {
    long minEmailGap = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 16; // 16 hours in milliseconds

    File file = new File("/TimestampForMyJob.txt");

    if (file.exists() == false) {
      file.createNewFile();
    }
    else {
      long currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();

      if (file.lastModified() + minEmailGap > currentTime) {
        cancel = true;
      }
      else {
        file.setLastModified(currentTime);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(IOException e) {
    // We can't tell whether the e-mail should be sent out or not, so we do nothing
    // and it just gets sent anyway - probably the best we can do with this exception.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no plugin that can do that for you. The default email feature in Jenkins is very simple and it works fine. There is [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) though, and this one can do lot more for you.

First of all, with Email-ext, you can configure a specific trigger to send the email notification - it can be on *success* or *failure*, which is similar to the default behaviour of Jenkins. But then you have the more refined one, like *First failure* and *Still failing*. This will give you a great deal of control on when and to whom (Recipients list, Commiter or Requester) your Jenkins will send an email. In my case a good configuration here will help a lot with email traffic generated by Jenkins. And you can send **specific** emails in specific situation to specific list of people - great!

The other option, if you really do not need that level of control and want to just to limit the email traffic to one summary per day is to set up a mailing list. Most mailing list engines will let you send a *daily digest* of all email traffic to the list. It should be enough, although I really do not feel like it is actually a good option on the long term. I would definitely give a try to Email-ext plugin.

Comment: digest email is a good idea but it looks like a workaround to me . Currently i have configured 2 jobs in my jenkins - one that runs every hour and the other one that runs only at a specific time so that it sends only one success email

Comment: It always will be a workaround. Let's face it - there is no feature like that. BUT you can write your on plugin to do whatever you want it to do. Still, besides the regular features and the extended email plugin features there is not much you can do *out-of-the-box*