# Is possible to send a single email notification for several jobs?

Tags: jenkins

We run several jobs daily under different views and get an email notification for each job, is it possible to set up Jenkins so that it sends an email summary containing the results of several jobs under the same view?

installing plug ins is not an option, I'm not permitted to do so :(.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Doubtful without plugins. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173455/jenkins-sending-success-email-only-once-a-day-though-the-job-is-running-hour

Comment: Are you permitted to create other jobs? You can create a job and let it check and summary the results of other jobs, then let it send the email using the summarized report.

Comment: @Chong, Yes I am, thank you, that's a great Idea :)

Comment: But if you are not able to install any plugins, it might be a tough task to check results of other jobs as you need to check build information of each job manually by going through specific folders. I would suggest you ask your administrator for permission to install plugins like https://plugins.jenkins.io/buildresult-trigger (this one is not famous but really useful)